# How to assign a new number to a variable, given the same number in advance?

Tags: python

If the given number is less than the 2, it asks to reenter the number by using recursion.

I've first given 2 and then after recursion, I gave 3, but the output is still 2.

How to output 3?

```
def inexpno():
    exp = int(input("Enter the Experiment n.o : "))  # Takes a exp number
    if exp<=2:  # Enter your completed experiment here
        print("It is completed Correction for both Record and Observation\n\n")
        print("Do you want to select another experiment")
        we = input("")
        if we == "yes" or we == "YES":
            inexpno()                              #  TO CHANGE
        else:
            exit()
    return exp


print(inexpno())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you don't save the return value from `inexpno()` in the recursive call on line 8. You simply need to save it as `exp`:

```
exp = inexpno()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your recursive line to

```
return inexpno()
```